# Why doesn't my HVAC system use the away temperature setting?

Tags: hvac

I have a Carrier Infinity dual-fuel 5 stage HP w furnace. I set the away temp much lower than the home temp but the HP keeps running to bring the temp up to the next home temp.  I would think the system would shut off until the time gets closer to the next heat in call.  Is this normal or is there a

Comment: Welcome. Looks like you posted before finishing your last sentence. You can revise to fix that. Also, what's an "HP w furnace"? Please don't use uncommon abbreviations. If that's a model number, say so.

Comment: I'd bet "HP w/furnace" == "Heat pump with emergency electric resistance heat"

Comment: What model of thermostat is running the system (this is where the problem usually is).

Comment: Is your system a heat pump with a gas furnace backup, or a heat pump with electric backup strip heat?

Answer (score 1):

My thermostat has this feature. It also has another feature (I cannot remember if that one is togglable) that tries to get the inside temperature to your desired home temperature by the time you get home.

So as an example, say away is 66° and home is 70°. Say home is set to 5 PM. My thermostat will turn the heat on before 5 PM *(assuming it is colder than 70°)* to try to make it my desired temperature as soon as I am home.

It's hard to tell if your system is doing this, you did mention "shut off until the time gets closer" which sounds like what I described. So if that's the case, I offer this alternative thought.

You mentioned away is set "much lower" than home. It can actually take a while for a house's temperature to change. Maybe your unit is better at heating your home than the thermostat thinks it is (e.g., maybe your home is small or your unit is powerful) so it turns it on earlier than it should. I don't know anything about your thermostat, but assuming it doesn't have some kind of learning feature the simplest thing may be to set the home time a few hours later than you actually want it.